# Plot Graphics Copy/Paste Error

Tags: graphics

During copying/pasting of the Graphics output from ListLinePlot and ListPlot, I regularly but inconsistently have a pasted image that has issue with the image bounding. For example,
[image: Bad Bounding]

This occurs with both direct copying as well as with "Copy AS Bitmap" when the copied Graphics is pasted OUTSIDE of Mathematica. Pasting within Mathematica the bounding is as expected.

Re-evaluating SetOptions[ListLinePlot, ...] with typical arguments does not correct the issue. Only closing and re-opening the Kernel corrects the issue. Closing and re-opening the Notebook does not correct the issue.

Nothing seems obvious bad in Reviewing the FullForm of the Graphics object. Excluding the long list of data, the FullFrom output is below.

```
List[List[], List[]]], Rule[AspectRatio, Power[GoldenRatio, -1]], 
 Rule[Axes, List[True, True]], Rule[AxesLabel, List[None, None]], 
 Rule[AxesOrigin, List[0, 22.`]], 
 Rule[BaseStyle, 
  List[Rule[FontFamily, "Gill Sans MT"], Rule[FontSize, 14]]], 
 Rule[DisplayFunction, Identity], 
 Rule[Epilog, 
  List[List[Arrow[List[List[15, 24], List[14.5`, 22.6`]]], 
    Inset["7AM", List[15, 24.2`]]]]], 
 Rule[Frame, List[List[True, True], List[True, True]]], 
 Rule[FrameLabel, 
  List[List["Temperature (C)", None], List["Hours into Test", None]]],
  Rule[FrameTicks, 
  List[List[Automatic, Automatic], List[Automatic, Automatic]]], 
 Rule[GridLines, List[Automatic, Automatic]], 
 Rule[GridLinesStyle, Directive[GrayLevel[0.5`, 0.4`]]], 
 Rule[ImageSize, 500], Rule[LabelStyle, Directive[Bold]], 
 Rule[Method, 
  List[Rule["OptimizePlotMarkers", True], 
   Rule["OptimizePlotMarkers", True], 
   Rule["CoordinatesToolOptions", 
    List[Rule["DisplayFunction", 
      Function[
       List[Identity[Part[Slot[1], 1]], Identity[Part[Slot[1], 2]]]]],
      Rule["CopiedValueFunction", 
      Function[
       List[Identity[Part[Slot[1], 1]], 
        Identity[Part[Slot[1], 2]]]]]]]]], 
 Rule[PlotRange, List[List[0, 16.6`], List[22, 26]]], 
 Rule[PlotRangeClipping, True], 
 Rule[PlotRangePadding, 
  List[List[Scaled[0.02`], Scaled[0.02`]], List[0, 0]]], 
 Rule[Ticks, List[Automatic, Automatic]]]
```

Comment: Where do you paste it to? There is even a difference between MS word and MS powerpoint. Pasting is always errorprone unfortunately

Comment: The paste location does not make a difference. It could be Word, Outlook email, Powerpoint or MSPaint. Same error. But then restart the kernel and all is happy again.

Comment: Which version are you using and what os?

Comment: 12.1.1.0 64-bit on Win10

Comment: I'll try to duplicate on my system. Monday earliest. After how much time does it occur?

Comment: Thanks for trying. Very irregular. It does seem to happen more regularly when I have multiple open notebooks distributed across my 3 monitor setup.

Comment: Hi, I can't reproduce .. I have only 1 monitor